# OpenCV Version for Android Source Build

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, android-source

I have to use Android 4.2/4.3 on a portable device that has camera as well
I built Android OS from its source, and I have to build a native module as a shared library by putting my code into `Android/external` directory. 
This is not an external app but a module that is supposed to be internally used by other native modules that reside in `Android/external`

My module makes use of OpenCV.
As I understood, my native build's dependency on OpenCV is different as compared to how an Android app makes use of OpenCV through JNI.

For an app, we can use the newer versions of OpenCV library (e.g. 2.x 3.x), but for internal build, Android only has OpenCV 1.1 which is very old. (So old that it does not have support for C++ STD, and it also lacks all the new functionality)

**Is there a way to make use of newer versions of OpenCV to build native modules for internal usage in Android?**

I tried to add OpenCV 2.4.13 but it gives lots of errors. I used ndk-build and mm, both failed with errors.
Any help in this will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Here are few of the errors I get:

```
=======================
/android/external/ImageProcessing$ mm
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.2.2
TARGET_PRODUCT=IPLA20T1
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.2.0-27-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-14.04-trusty
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=JDQ39
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/Effect_Tick.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/KeypressStandard_120.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/KeypressSpacebar_120.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/KeypressDelete_120.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/KeypressReturn_120.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/VideoRecord.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/VideoRecord.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/camera_click.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/camera_click.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/LowBattery.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/LowBattery.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/Dock.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/Dock.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/Undock.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/Undock.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/Lock.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/Lock.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/base/data/sounds/effects/ogg/Unlock.ogg:system/media/audio/ui/Unlock.ogg ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/es-ES_zl0_sg.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/es-ES_zl0_sg.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/es-ES_ta.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/es-ES_ta.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/de-DE_gl0_sg.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/de-DE_gl0_sg.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/it-IT_ta.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/it-IT_ta.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/fr-FR_ta.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/fr-FR_ta.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/fr-FR_nk0_sg.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/fr-FR_nk0_sg.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/it-IT_cm0_sg.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/it-IT_cm0_sg.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES device/softwinner/IPLA20T1/googleservice/gapps-jb-20130301-signed/system/tts/lang_pico/de-DE_ta.bin:system/tts/lang_pico/de-DE_ta.bin ignored.
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES frameworks/native/data/etc/android.hardware.wifi.direct.xml:system/etc/permissions/android.hardware.wifi.direct.xml ignored.
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE IPLA20T1
make: Entering directory `/media/3TBHDD/usman/T1_REV4_V37/android'
target thumb C++: libDSM_ImageProcessing <= external/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.cpp
In file included from > external/ImageProcessing/stdafx.h:43:0,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.cpp:4:
> external/ImageProcessing/../../ScenarioEngine/core/hb/tplcrt.h:40:1: warning: identifier 'nullptr' will become a keyword in C++0x [-Wc++0x-compat]
In file included from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv/cv.h:64:0,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuAR.h:15,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuARDetector.h:4,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.cpp:7:
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1334:18: error: 'class cv::_InputArray' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:1422:18: error: 'class cv::_OutputArray' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
In file included from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/params.h:33:0,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:41,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp:50,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv/cv.h:69,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuAR.h:15,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuARDetector.h:4,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.cpp:7:
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:40:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::base_any_policy' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In member function 'virtual const std::type_info& cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<T>::type()':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:60:59: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: At global scope:
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<cvflann::flann_centers_init_t>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::flann_centers_init_t>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:102:60:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:57:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<cvflann::flann_centers_init_t>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::flann_centers_init_t>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:102:60:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::flann_centers_init_t>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<cvflann::flann_algorithm_t>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::flann_algorithm_t>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:107:57:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:57:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<cvflann::flann_algorithm_t>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::flann_algorithm_t>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:107:57:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::flann_algorithm_t>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:187:59:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:57:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:187:59:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<cvflann::anyimpl::empty_any>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In member function 'T& cvflann::any::cast()':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:262:39: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In member function 'const T& cvflann::any::cast() const':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:271:39: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In member function 'bool cvflann::any::empty() const':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:279:59: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In member function 'bool cvflann::any::compatible(const cvflann::any&) const':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:292:49: error: no match for 'operator==' in '((cvflann::anyimpl::base_any_policy*)((const cvflann::any*)this)->cvflann::any::policy)->cvflann::anyimpl::base_any_policy::type() == ((cvflann::anyimpl::base_any_policy*)x.cvflann::any::policy)->cvflann::anyimpl::base_any_policy::type()'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:292:49: note: candidates are:
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:7:24: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:7:24: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:7:24: note: template<class _Key, class _Compare, class _Value, class _KeyOfValue, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::priv::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Compare, _Value, _KeyOfValue, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::priv::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Compare, _Value, _KeyOfValue, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_complex.h:704:24: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const _Tp&, const std::complex<_Tp2>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_complex.h:700:24: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::complex<_Tp2>&, const _Tp&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_complex.h:696:24: note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::complex<_Tp2>&, const std::complex<_Tp2>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_istreambuf_iterator.h:110:24: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_string_operators.h:320:1: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_string_operators.h:311:1: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_string_operators.h:287:1: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_relops_cont.h:7:24: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_alloc.h:381:24: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_T1>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_iterator.h:113:25: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
external/stlport/stlport/stl/_pair.h:81:24: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In member function 'bool cvflann::any::has_type()':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:299:42: error: cannot use typeid with -fno-rtti
In file included from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:42:0,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp:50,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv/cv.h:69,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuAR.h:15,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuARDetector.h:4,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.cpp:7:
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/saving.h: In function 'cvflann::IndexHeader cvflann::load_header(FILE*)':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/saving.h:113:63: error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable
In file included from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/params.h:33:0,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:41,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann.hpp:50,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv/cv.h:69,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuAR.h:15,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/RyuARDetector.h:4,
                 from > external/ImageProcessing/ImageProcessing.cpp:7:
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: At global scope:

> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:240:24:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::operator=(const T&) [with T = int, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/params.h:49:29:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:57:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<int>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::small_any_policy<int>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<int>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:231:9:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::assign(const T&) [with T = int, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:240:24:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::operator=(const T&) [with T = int, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/params.h:49:29:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:65:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::small_any_policy<int>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<float>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:65:8:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::small_any_policy<float>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<float>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:231:9:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::assign(const T&) [with T = float, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:240:24:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::operator=(const T&) [with T = float, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/params.h:51:26:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:57:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<float>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::small_any_policy<float>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<float>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:231:9:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::assign(const T&) [with T = float, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:240:24:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::operator=(const T&) [with T = float, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/params.h:51:26:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:65:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::small_any_policy<float>' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<bool>':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:65:8:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::small_any_policy<bool>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<bool>'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:231:9:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::assign(const T&) [with T = bool, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
...
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:68:31:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:57:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::typed_base_any_policy<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h: In instantiation of 'cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >':
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:168:33:   instantiated from 'cvflann::anyimpl::SinglePolicy<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:231:9:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::assign(const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:240:24:   instantiated from 'cvflann::any& cvflann::any::operator=(const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, cvflann::any = cvflann::any]'
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/flann_base.hpp:68:31:   instantiated from here
> external/ImageProcessing/opencv_latest/include/opencv2/flann/any.h:79:8: error: 'struct cvflann::anyimpl::big_any_policy<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >' has virtual functions and accessible non-virtual destructor [-Werror=non-virtual-dtor]
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [out/target/product/IPLA20T1/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libDSM_ImageProcessing_intermediates/ImageProcessing.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory
```

Comment: Maybe you can expand on *"failed with errors"*? Did you build OpenCV from sources, or used the prebuilt libs?

Comment: No I didn't build OpenCV from source. I believe these are compilation errors not link errors.

Comment: Apparently, your settings for external/ImageProcessing are not correct. Maybe, this lib is not compatible with OpenCV 3.0. I would try to build this library as standalone with ndk-build, and then use the result as a prebuilt binary: for myself, tuning ndk-build environment is easier than the huge and less flexible system build tree.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll try to build library myself though I suspect this is an issue with toolchain etc. where some headers or some definitions are missing because of the limitations of Android system. I think of this because within the android's source tree the OpenCV version in their master source is 1.1, and they have mentioned: "Please note that due to platform and project constraints this is NOT the latest version of OpenCV!"
I'm trying to use OpenCV 2.4.13 (not 3.0), and I have to use this because OpenCV 1.1 misses most of the useful functionality and it is only C API

Comment: I understand your motives, but I don't think there are toolchain limitations. I recommend not to replace the OpenCV project in the system tree (the major releases are not backwards compatible, there probably are system components that won't build with the new API). If you use OpenCV as static libs in your module, then there is no coexistence problem.